# Add middleware to default Compojure project

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have worked with the Compojure Leiningen template with my code but now I'm struggling to add middleware. For reference, this is the default project:

```
(ns test.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

My code functionally doesn't deviate from this.
I would like to add the [[bk/ring-gzip "0.3.0"]](https://github.com/bertrandk/ring-gzip) middleware. I understand the concept but I haven't been able to find the syntax which extends this configuration.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example on the bk/ring-gzip site just needs adapting slightly. The routes returned from compojure are a handler; the wrappers take a handler and return a handler. If you need other handlers they should be before gzip if they act on the request or response bodies.

```
(def app (-> app-routes
    (wrap-defaults site-defaults)
    (wrap-gzip)))
```

It's normally preferred to use the threading macro form as you may have several middlewares to compose, but you could just call functions.

Comment: That's working, thank you! Though I thought it would apply gzip encoding to the site resources too, is that within the scope of this code? It might just be a limitation of the middleware I'm using... Edit: looking at [the source](https://github.com/bertrandk/ring-gzip/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/gzip.clj#L49) there's a file extension whitelist.